# Associating function passed as argument with a number

Tags: javascript, function, onchange

I'm trying to use the following code in Javascript. I'd like to pass a function *rulefunc()* a number of times into the *onChange()* function iteratively. I want to be able to access *i* from within the function when it is called. How can I do this?

```
var gui = new DAT.GUI();

for   for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {

  // want to associate ruleFunc with i
  gui.add(lsys, 'grammarString').onChange(ruleFunc);

}

function ruleFunc(newVal) {
  ...
  // access i here
}
```

Comment: check my answer if it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a function that returns a function like

```
function ruleFunc(i) {

  return function(newVal){
     // ... here use your newVal and i
  }

}
```

And use like

```
f1.add(lsys, 'grammarString').onChange(ruleFunc(i));
```

You call the function that gets the `i` from the outer scope and then the returned function gets the `newVal` of the 'onChange' event. Note that I am calling the function `ruleFunc` and pass a parameter `i`. Inside the function you can now use your `i` variable and `newVal`.

Example of how it works. Here I add functions to the array with approprite `i` values. After that when I execute each function, it properly knows what `i` was used when it have been created. It is called [**closure**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

```js
var functions = [];

function ruleFunc(newVal) {
  return function (){
    console.log(newVal);
  };
}

for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  functions.push(ruleFunc(i));
}

for(var i = 0; i < functions.length; i++) {
  functions[i]();
}
```

Comment: But doesn't newVal need to be used to access the value has been changed in gui?

Comment: @user2260199 Sorry. Edited

Comment: Isnt it better to use an IIFE while pushing to the functions array so that right value is passed then and there, rather than iterating over it again? @SurenSrapyan

Comment: @RahulArora Any difference ? That is also a solution.

Comment: @SurenSrapyan: yes that way you save running for loop again.

Answer (score 1):

**At the event side:**

Here since for loop is synchronous an IIFE is used so that right value of i is passed 
IIFE and the onchange event makes a closure which makes the right value of i to be passed
at the argument

**At the event callback side**

Closure is used so that the function that is returned can access the value of the argument

```
var gui = new DAT.GUI();

for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
     // want to associate ruleFunc with i
    (function(a){ //making an IIFE to make sure right value of i is passed to the function
        f1.add(lsys, 'grammarString').onChange(ruleFunc(a));
    })(i);
}

function ruleFunc(newVal) {
    return function(){ 
        //making a closure which will have access to the argument passed to the outer function
        console.log(newVal); 
    }

}
```